# Calculate Hours between 2 Time Inputs

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, time, jquery-calculation

So i have 2 input fields(BeginTime and EndTime) and a user can insert time with a time picker plugin called [Datebox](http://dev.jtsage.com/DateBox/) using the 24 Hour time Format. 
 On Change those inputs should calculate the hours between those times.
e.g
 BeginTime: 08:00 
        EndTime:16:00 
 Result: 8 Hours
Times like
BeginTime:18:00
EndTime:02:00
Result: 8 Hours
 Should also be possible same goes with negative Hours
Now i only can manage to get the hours between Positive times and only with begintime > endtime here is my code:

```
var timehour = end.split('.')[0] - begin.split('.')[0];
var timeminut = end.split('.')[1] - begin.split('.')[1];

        if (timeminut< 0){
            timehour--;
            timeminut= 60 + timeminut;
        }...giving out the result
```

So how do i calculate the other time possibilities?
 **P.S i am using jquery mobile**

Comment: Something like this: http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/qNzZAb. How do you know when to get negative hours versus moving end time to next day?

Comment: Hey, yea something like that. Well lets say i work in shifts from like 06:00 - 14:00 and 14:00 - 22:00 and 22:00 - 06:00. I would probably create 3 variables(boolean) and check which is active and then set the appropriate calculation option something like that.

Comment: Where do negative hours come in?

Comment: just if the beginn time is greater than the end time but it looks like it is already working